# Mobx state tree getting started part 2

Tags: mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

Does anyone know if there's a second part of the getting started available?

I can see there is an annotation about the second part but actually there is no link nor any further information about it. At least I can't find it. Anyone knows?

> Next up
>   In part 2 of this tutorial, we will discover how to use MST life cycle hooks and local state to fetch user data from an XHR endpoint, and see how environments will help dealing with dependency injection of the parameters needed to fetch our endpoint. We will implement auto-save using MobX helpers and learn more about patches and actions event streams.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it's not yet available: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree/commit/877b71c202f5d78b9aff0a5f00173b3634dbb4f6#diff-a39c9f7aa728d5fa3b973bc6ba49228aR596